# Webpage rendering double width in mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make this website work on mobile for a couple of hours now, nothing seems to work. The oly thing i can think of is that some element is going beyond its desired container generating additional width. Any help would be appreciated.

website link: https://ismailsultan.github.io/icantspellyourname/

code(im fairly new to github): https://github.com/ismailsultan/icantspellyourname

note: this is only html and css because i dont know much about js and the little bit that there is on the page is not written by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG has an explicit width set on it that exceeds the width of its container.

<svg class="header-image" id="a9370ae1-210a-4918-a96d-edf406e909af" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" **width="1086"** **height="811.37"** viewBox="0 0 1086 811.37">

I stink at working with SVGs so I can't really tell you the best way to make that graphic responsive, but that is what is causing the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing it out, it worked out after a little bit of min-width and stuff